# Correct way to return Dictionary values sorted

Tags: objective-c, swift, sorting, dictionary

I have a `Site` class with a dictionary of `Valve` objects. E.g.

```
class Site {
    var valves:[String:Valve] = [:]
    ...
}
```

My `Valve` class has a custom sorting function called `uiCompare()`. I want to add a function to `Site` that returns the valves as a sorted array. Following the compiler's nagging... I came up with

```
class Site {
    ...

    func sortedValves() -> [Valve] {
        return self.valves.allValues().sorted { $0.uiCompare($1) }
    }
}
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
[String:Valve] does not have a member named 'allValues'
```

So I'm confused. Isn't that an `NSDictionary` still? I was porting this code from the following `objc` code:

```
- (NSMutableArray*) sortedValves {
    NSMutableArray *sorted = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: self.valves.allValues];
    [sorted sortUsingSelector: @selector(uiCompare:)];
    return sorted;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift's `Dictionary` and Cocoa's `NSDictionary` are bridgeable, but are not the same thing. There is a performance cost to transforming a `Dictionary` to a `NSDictionary`. Additionally, while any `NSDictionary` can be converted to a `Dictionary`, not all `Dictionary` objects can be converted to `NSDictionary` objects. Understandably, then, their interface is somewhat different.

I'm often confused by what has a `sort`/`sorted` method, a `map` method or a `filter` method. Now I just use the free functions, which seem to work across the board, for the sake of consistency.

```
sorted(valves.values) { $0.uiCompare($1) }
```

This returns an array.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get an unordered iterable collection of all of a dictionary’s values, use `values` of method of [Dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Dictionary.html)

And to initialize a new array with the values property,

Try `return Array(valves.values).sorted { $0.uiCompare($1) }`

for swift

Comment: Gets rid of the allValues error. But replaces it with LazyForwardCollection<...> does not have a member named sorted

Comment: Updated the answer, `.values` was not returning an Array. Try now.

Comment: I also found that I could use `return sorted(valves.values) { ... }`. I hate the mix of loose functions and object bound messages. But I'm curious which (if either) is the more idiomatic?

Answer (score 1):

```
 var valves:[String:Valve] = [:]
```

> So I'm confused. Isn't that an NSDictionary still? I

No. This is a Swift Dictionary which is inherently different to an NSDictionary. 
To keep NSDictionary functionalities / methods use

```
var valves = NSDictionary() //or initialised with keys and values or optional or NSMutableDictionary or whatever you need
```

Or convert the Dictionary to NSDictionary